# How to install both ROS jade and indigo together

Tags: ros, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm working on a 64-bit system with Ubuntu 14.04. I already have `ros-jade-desktop-full` installed but I'd like to switch to indigo because I need to use the Baxter robot. I'm having trouble installing `ros-indigo-desktop-full`. It's giving me an error:

```
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to execute the command `sudo apt-get install libsdformat1`, it attempts to uninstall all of ros-jade which I do not want to happen. Is there a way of installing indigo without uninstalling jade?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228115/how-to-install-both-ros-jade-and-indigo-together/) by [atoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26090/atoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-04**:
Usually this should just simply work. Have you tried executing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or some other apt-get dependency conflict trouble shooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was in a hurry so I ended up uninstalling jade and installing indigo. I assume it is something to do with the 2 different gazebo versions for each distro because even after I uninstalled jade, it didn't let me install indigo until I uninstalled some independent `jade-gazebo` packages.

---

Originally posted by [atoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26090/atoz/) with karma: 58 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-07**:
I converted your comment to an answer. Please mark it as correct if your problem is solved.

**Comment by [atoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26090/atoz/) on 2016-03-20**:
I'd actually prefer to be able to install both so I'd like a solution to this if one is available

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-03-27**:
If you are using the OSRF backports of gazebo they may collide. If you use the default versions of ROS packages they are installable side by side.